# Get all fields and data in Drupal 10

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal 10 instance on my local machine. I want to get all content types and their fields and the data with SQL.

So if you have for example "article" I want to get the article's Title, Body, Tags, Files (at least as ids), and basically, everything attached to the article.

I was thinking that if I manage to read the blob in the "config" table I would have at least the information about the content type's fields but I was wrong.

I was trying to understand how the CMS is getting the information about the content types by looking at the PHP code but got no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Get article using entity query
  use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->condition('status', 1);
  $results = $query->execute();

  // get value of article results

  $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($results);
  foreach($nodes as $node_key=>$node_value){
    $node_data[] = [
      "title" => $node_value->title->value,
      "body" => $node_value->body->value,
      "tags_id" => $node_value->field_tags->target_id,
      "file_id" => $node_value->field_image->target_id];
  }
```